# SQL: Get records created in time range for specific dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a set of records that were created last week, and from those I want to retrieve only those that were created between 6h45 and 19h15. I have a column `creation_date` that I can use.

How can I do this in sql?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Oracle we can turn dates into numbers and apply arithmetic to them in a variety of ways.

For instance `sysdate-7` gives us the date seven days ago.  `trunc(some_date)` removes the time element from a date column.  And `to_char(some_date, 'SSSSS')` gives us its time element as the number of seconds since midnight.  So 06:45:00 is 24300 seconds and 18:15:59 is 69359 seconds (please check those numbers, as they are back-of-an-envelope figgerin').

Anyway, putting that all together in a single query like this ...

```
select *
from your_table
where creation_date >= trunc(sysdate)-7
and to_number(to_char(creation_date, 'sssss')) between 24300 and 69359
```

... wil produce all the records created in the last week with a time element within core hours.

Comment: +1, but won't that bring back records from this week as well?

Comment: Well there's an ambiguity in "last week".  I took that to mean "last seven days" but you presumably meant something different.

Comment: thanks guys,it works as i wanted , "last seven days" is what i meant.

Answer (score 3):

This query would return any records created in the last 7 days with the time portion of their create date between 6:45am and 7:15pm.

```
select * 
  from your_table
 where creation_date > sysdate - 7
   and to_char(creation_date, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '06:45:00' 
   and to_char(creation_date, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '19:15:00'
```

Comment: +1, but won't that bring back records from this week as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on criteria above, this will bring back records from the last week between Sunday and Saturday in the hours of 06:45:00 and 19:15:59.

You can adjust the " - 7" and the " + 6" to different numbers if you'd like the week range to be different (for instance, if your week is Monday through Sunday).

```
select * 
from your_table
where creation_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'WW') - 7
and creation_date <= (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'WW') - 7) + 6
and to_char(creation_date, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '06:45:00' 
and to_char(creation_date, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '19:15:00'
```

Comment: thanks for answering , but i have different dates in my table not a specific one like 02/27/2012

Comment: @MMC - so, you want this to be dynamic?  Like, do you want to just grab records that are 7 days old regardless of what day you run it on?

Comment: yes those created last week but also if i replace 02/27/2012  by today's date i dont want to get for example records created yesterday at 06:30

Comment: No need for dynamic SQL, Oracle has a panoply of useful date functions.

Comment: @MMC - edited my answer again based on what Dougman and APC posted which is much cleaner...