# Select based on a time-of-day

Tags: oracle, date

I have an Oracle DATE column with, for example, these values:

```
      RUN_DATE
-------------------
2012-06-09 13:15:00
2012-06-10 14:28:00
2012-06-11 12:20:00
2012-06-12 13:14:00
2012-06-13 11:50:00
```

I want to select those values that occurred within a hour of 13:00.
For the data above that would be the 1st, 3rd, and 4th rows.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Get records created in time range for specific dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568787/sql-get-records-created-in-time-range-for-specific-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE to_char(run_date, 'HH24:MI' ) between '12:00' and '14:00'
```

will work.  Of course, you'll probably need a function-based index on `to_char(run_date, 'HH24:MI' )` to make it run efficiently.